# how to check email sending delivery report

Tags: android

i m sending email from my application...my application uses inbuilt application to send email.
how could i know whether my mail was sent or not...?

is there any way to check delivery report in android?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think so, there is no way to find it from your application. Sorry !!